# Как испольузуя ActionColumn скрыть кнопки?

Tags: php, yii2

В `\backend\views\user\index.php`

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'username',
        //'password_hash',
        'id_role',
        'comment:ntext',
        // 'created_at',
        // 'ban_date',
        // 'status',
        // 'auth_key:ntext',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],            

    ],
]); ?>
```

Как мне скрыть кнопку удаления в зависимости от роли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$userId = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
$roles = array_keys(Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($userId));
if (in_array("admin", $roles))
{
$buttons =   ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{view} {update} {delete}',
            ];
}
else 
{
    $buttons =   ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{view}',
            ];
}
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'username',
        //'password_hash',
        'id_role',
        'comment:ntext',
        // 'created_at',
        // 'ban_date',
        // 'status',
        // 'auth_key:ntext',

        $buttons

    ],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'buttonOptions' => [
        'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
        'class' => 'btn btn-default'
    ],
    'headerOptions' => [
        'style' => 'width:165px;'
    ],
    'visibleButtons' => [
        'delete' => Yii::$app->user->can('admin'),
    ]
],
```