# Как используя ActionColumn скрыть/показать кнопки в определенной строке?

Tags: php, yii2

Использую стандартный `GridView::widget`. Подскажите как в ActionColumn отобразить по условию в одной строке только просмотр (`{view}`), а в другой просмотр и удаление (`{view} {delete}`).

Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432564/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-actioncolumn-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8) почти мой случай, только в этом примере меняется набор управляющих кнопок во всей таблице, а мне нужно построчно.

Comment: @user3127286 Премного благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C версии 2.0.7 в ActionColumn доступен параметр visibleButtons

```
[
    'class' => ActionColumn::className(),
    'visibleButtons' => [
        'update' => function ($model, $key, $index) {
            return $model->status === 'editable';
        }
    ]
]
```

[Тут](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/fe8a0a6a2ed09ae5b255e7f3b3e16c16d8789e3a/framework/grid/ActionColumn.php#L95) подробнее